# VBA automation error: -2147221080 (800401a8)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code whereby everything works fine except one line that keeps getting the automation error even though the sheet exists. My code is supposed to delete sheets based on a certain name column and despite editing it, the error still occurs. Would appreciate if someone could help me out here, thanks!

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()

Const lngNameCol = 8 ' names in column (H)
' lngRow = 5 ' data start in row 5

Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim row_num As Long

Dim wsh_to_delete As Worksheet
Dim main_sheet As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set main_sheet = ActiveSheet

lastrow = main_sheet.Range("A" & main_sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For row_num = 5 To lastrow
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            If ws.Name = main_sheet.Cells(row_num, lngNameCol).Value Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Worksheets(ws.Name).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

The automation error occurs here:

```
If ws.Name = main_sheet.Cells(row_num, lngNameCol).Value Then
```

Although the code deleted the sheets, the error keeps popping out after every row

Comment: 1. at which row_num does the failure occur? 2. does the error changes when you remove "On Error Resume Next" and "On Error Goto 0"?

Comment: Write `MsgBox main_sheet.Cells(row_num, lngNameCol).Value` before the error comes. What is the result?

Comment: @denyo at row 6, there will already be an automation error and the error doesn't change even after adding the "on error resume next"

Comment: @vityata it gives the correct value data in the cell, a string but strangely after i choose to end the code upon the error, the sheet is still deleted accurately

Comment: `If Not ws Is Nothing Then` is a bit of a useless check - it is not needed, because `ws` is always not nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the deletion of the worksheet during the loop.

Try your loops the other way around, cycling through each sheet to see if it is the name you're looking for:

```
For row_num = 5 To lastrow
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            If ws.Name = main_sheet.Cells(row_num, lngNameCol).Value Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Worksheets(ws.Name).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: yes, after putting it the other way round, it worked fine! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

When you delete element from a collection, the whole collection is a bit "unhappy". With the worksheets, the best way is to loop from the total count of the worksheets to 1 and check whether your worksheet should be deleted:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "Something" And Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Additionally, there is a rule for `Worksheets.Count>1`, because the last worksheet of the workbook cannot be deleted.

Comment: thanks for the tip but for mine, i have to loop through the worksheets and a column of data to find a match before i delete, that's why i didn't use this instead

Answer (score 0):

I've started receiving an execution error when calling a userform. Thought my file was to large and started calling userform with VBA open. Worked for the most part but occasionally would still get the error. Noticed I had one of my sheets stating, sheets("sheet name").activate instead of "select" during the userform initialization. Once I changed this functionality, I haven't had the issue. TBD if long term solution.